# How to ensure SQL operations are committed or aborted as a unit in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a script called Taskcomplete.php that has 2 different queries.  1 update and 1 for insertion they both hav to be executed one after the other? How can I make sure that they both executed? For instance I have 2 tables 1 for Profiles(P) and the other for Comments(C) . When a user creates a new comment I update the Profiles table and add +1 to CommentNumbers and then I do an insertion into the Comments table with the new comment. If for instance 1 query fails I want to make sure that the other one does not go through, is there someway I can check? I am using Php and MySQL.

Comment: You need to use transactions (and innodb tables)

Comment: While transactions are certainly one approach, in general it's a bad idea to store data which can be easily derived from othe stored data.

Comment: Oh ok I see what your saying so do you think it would be better then to not use a transaction in my situation? so that if a user wants to know how many comments they have to just use a quick Count(*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can program two code blocks: one for inserting in Comments and one for updating profile table. 
But the most efficient solution to your problem is to use mysql Triggers.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER noofcomments 
AFTER INSERT ON comments 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   UPDATE profile
      SET profile.CommentNumbers = profile.CommentNumbers + 1
   WHERE profile.profileId = NEW.profileId
END; 
$$
DELIMITER;
```

Note:- The "NEW.profileId" is  the foreign key of the "comments" table and the primary key of the "profile" table.

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot that is exactly what I need to do. I will do the triggers now.